# SQL Query not getting the corresponding column

Tags: sql

```
SELECT t.title, Max(t.st) 
FROM (SELECT title, 
               Avg(stars) AS st 
        FROM movie 
               JOIN rating USING(mid) 
        GROUP BY title)t;
```

This is my  query which I am writing to get max values of `AVG(stars)` and it's corresponding title. Max value is coming fine but facing trouble in title. I am not getting corresponding title.

Output of subquery is:

```
Avatar                  4.0
E.T.                    2.5
Gone with the Wind      3.0
Raiders of the Lost Ark 3.33333333333
Snow White              4.5
The Sound of Music      2.5
```

**Output of whole query is wrong** .

```
The Sound of Music 4.5
```

**Expected /Correct output is**

```
SnowWhite 4.5
```

Comment: That query is invalid and shouldn't execute. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: jarlh is right; the query is invalid. You are aggregating your subquery data so as to get one result row containing the *maximum* st and, well, some title, you don't specify which. The DBMS should raise an error telling you that you haven't told it which title to select. Are you using MySQL maybe? (MySQL let's this slip and converts `t.title` to `ANY_VALUE(t.title)` silently when not in strict mode. If this is MySQL, then which version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select t.title,
       t.st
  from 
(select title,
        avg(stars) as st,rank() over(order by avg(stars) desc) as rSt
   from movie 
   join rating using(mID)
  group by title)t where t.rSt=1  ;
```

It is ranking movies in descending order first, then in outer query's where condition, movie with highest rank is being selected. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
select *
from 
(select title,
        avg(stars) as st
   from movie  a
   join rating b on a.mID=b.mID
  group by title
)t where st in
  (select max(st) from (select title,
        avg(stars) as st
   from movie  a
   join rating b on a.mID=b.mID
   group by title
  )t1 on t.title=t1.title)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use WHERE condition in your query. You can experiment with joins or just use subquery.

```
Select title, max(stars) 
from table 
where stars = (select max(stars) from table)
```

or

```
SELECT top 1 title
FROM table
ORDER BY Stars DESC
```